# Flexbox grid align images center

Tags: html, css

I want to align the images and text in the centre using flexbox

The image side by side and the text below the images

It was working before, however all of a sudden the images are just placed on the left hand side.

I have tried re-writing the HTML & CSS code however I am still getting the same output

I have no idea why it suddenly changed.

[image]

```css
.buy-coffee-wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(34, 25, 25);
}

.enjoy-home {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.buy-coffee {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Multi', sans-serif;
}

.coffee-almond,
.coffee-cookieDough,
.coffee-vanilla {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.coffee-almond:hover,
.coffee-cookieDough:hover,
.coffee-vanilla:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10;
}

.coffee-name,
.coffee-price {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell packaging1-wrapper">
      <img src="./img/coffee-cookieDough.png" class="responsive-image coffee-cookieDough">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Cookie Dough</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
    <img src="./img/coffee-almond.png" class="responsive-image coffee-almond">

    <h5 class="coffee-name">Amaretto Almond</h5>
    <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
    <img src="./img/coffee-vanilla.png" class="responsive-image coffee-vanilla">

    <h5 class="coffee-name">Very Vanilla</h5>
    <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? With that you can add d-flex align-items-center and justify-content-center on the .item element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basic raw terms this is how its done with css.

```css
BODY {
  background: #23191a;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.product {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="product">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1BXKfbX.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Journey to the center</h1>
      <p>The point that is equally distant from every point on the circumference of a circle or sphere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle too.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/56xevdo7/

It looks like your using a framework but its not bootstrap, you'll have to refer to the docs if its framework related.

Answer (score 1):

**Why**

The reason for your UI breakage was due to improperly closed `div`, especially the wrapper `<div class="grid">`

**How**

The layout is done using a wrapper `div` having flex direction `row`, so as to align all the `.cell` horizontally, And each '.cell' having flex direction `column` to vertically the contents inside them.

```
.grid{
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center; 
}
.cell{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

**Fixes**

I've followed the above mention method to resolve the issue. I hope even you would have intended to do the same approach.

I've created a working fiddle for reference, Please find the link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/kxeg8ufw/24/

**Output**
[image]

Note: I've used a dummy/sample image.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cell .responsive-image {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

...  will do it:

**Note:** you're closing the `.grid` element after you first `.cell`. You need to close it after the last one. If you want the products side-by-side only from a particular page width up, you should wrap the flex behavior on grid in a `@media` query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```css
.buy-coffee {

margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Multi', sans-serif;

}


.coffee-almond,
.coffee-cookieDough,
.coffee-vanilla {

width: 50%;
margin-left: 75px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

.coffee-almond:hover,
.coffee-cookieDough:hover,
.coffee-vanilla:hover{

border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
padding: 10;

}

.coffee-name, 
.coffee-price {

text-align: center;
margin-top: 25px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
}

body {background-color: #ccc}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cell .responsive-image {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell packaging1-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-cookieDough">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Cookie Dough</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-almond">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Amaretto Almond</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-vanilla">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Very Vanilla</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note: you really shouldn't add a separate class to each element in a collection, only to have to specify each of the classes in CSS, when all you need is the same behavior on all. The point of classes is to apply the same behavior to multiple elements (that's why I used `cell` and `image-responsive` classes).
When you want some specific behavior on one element, you probably should use `id`.

Another possible solution is to use block level elements with `margin:auto`, instead of flexbox:

```css
.cell:hover .responsive-image {
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10;
}

.cell * {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.coffee-name,
.coffee-price {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #ccc
}

.responsive-image {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell packaging1-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-cookieDough">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Cookie Dough</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-almond">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Amaretto Almond</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="cell packaging2-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image coffee-vanilla">

      <h5 class="coffee-name">Very Vanilla</h5>
      <h6 class="coffee-price">£2.49</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: OP Said `The image side by side and the text below the images`